# How could I iterate these two loops in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I am currently trying to program an array within an array and iterate the contents of the arrays. I'm not sure how to do this as the arrays are of a different type. I'm sure this can be resolved by creating at least two methods, one for the string and one for the int, but, I'm not sure how to iterate this as the first array is an ArrayList and the subsequent arrays are just lists. My question is this, how do I iterate into my first ArrayList and then iterate into the subsequent array? Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Unit {

    ArrayList<Item> unitInv;

    protected Unit (ArrayList<Item> inv) {
        unitInv = inv;
    }

    public Object[] itemName() { 
        Object[] itemName = unitInv.toArray(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { getItemName() 
            System.out.println(unitInv.toArray());
        }
        return itemName; 
    }

    public class Item {

        static String[] itemString;
        static int[] itemInt;

        public Item(String[] itemS, int[] itemI) {
        itemString = itemS;
        itemInt = itemI;
    }

    public static int getItemName() {
        int size = itemString.length;
        for (int i = 0; size < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(itemString[i]);
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm just not thinking about something simple here. I cant figure out how to get the value back from the Item itemString array via the itemName method in the item class. Thank you for your help!

Comment: where do you want to iterate the array ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `unitInv` is an arrayList of item `objects`. So you can directly access `itemString` and `itemInt` lists via object.

```
for (Item item : unitInv) {

    // access itemString
    String[] itemString = item.itemString; // or use getter

    // iterate through list
    for(String strItem : itemString) {
       System.out.println(strItem)
    } 

    // same applicable for itemInt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From how I see it, you have array of `Item`s  and each item have `String[]` and `int[]`.
So in order to iterate the `ArrayList` you need 1 loop, and for each `Item` you need 2 loops - one for `String[]` and one for `int[]`. It will look like this:

```
//suppose we have initialize unitInv 
ArrayList<Item> unitInv;

for(Item item : unitInv) {
    for(int iString = 0; iString < item.itemString.length; iString++) {
        //code for itemString array
    }

    for(int iInt = 0; iInt < item.itemInt.length; iInt++) {
        //code for itemInt array
    }
}
```